# How can I hide Dashboard notifications for just one particular plugin?

Tags: plugins, admin, dashboard

I have an orphaned plugin (removed from wordpress.org/plugins) that continues to spam me with review request notifications in the admin dashboard. I want to hide or disable just that one particular notification. And leave the rest of my notifications in place as-is.

I have found a code snippet to add to my child theme's functions.php file but it hides all notifications. How do I modify the below to be able to hide notifications for just one particular (or multiple) plugins, by plugin name as the parameter if possible? Here is what I found (for dismissable notices):

````
add_action('admin_head', 'bc_disable_notice'); function bc_disable_notice() { ?> <style> .notice.is-dismissible { display: none;} </style> <?php }```
````